# uploading high quality image on parse.com

Tags: android, database, image, upload, parse-platform

Whenever i upload any image to my database on parse.com, its size gets reduced. I have tried all possible ways to fix this issue. i tried saving the image in my sdcard and there, it was of proper size but when i try to view it in data browser of parse, it shows me a very small image, say of 50x50px. how can i fix this?

my saving to sd card code:

```
private void saveImage(Bitmap imgmap,ImageView imgview)
    {
        Calendar ci= Calendar.getInstance();
        fileNameStr="sdcard/Sudhaar/"+ci.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-"+(ci.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"-"+ci.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"_"+ci.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+"-"+ci.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+"-"+ci.get(Calendar.SECOND)+"-"+ci.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND)+".JPG";

        try
        {
            FileOutputStream imgout=new FileOutputStream(fileNameStr);
            imgData.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,imgout);
            imgout.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

My upload to parse code:

```
public void send_img(Bitmap imgData, String description)
    {

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imgData.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] img = stream.toByteArray();
            ParseFile file = new ParseFile("image.jpg", img);
            file.saveInBackground();
            ParseObject complain = new ParseObject("complaint");
                   complain.put("description",description);
                   complain.put("image", file);
                   complain.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                       public void done(ParseException e) {
                         if (e == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Complaint Posted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             pDialog.dismiss();
                             finish();
                         } else {
                             pDialog.dismiss();

                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry ! Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         }
                       }
                   });

                   } 

}
```

Comment: I've seen many complain that while it is easy to get the thumbnails in Android, there's much more work required to get the actual images. Perhaps do a search for that and see if you really are getting the full images, or are simply feeding thumbnails to Parse.

Answer (score 0):

Use a curl CLI interface to manually POST a file to parse.com

consult the 'rest api docs' section='uploading files'

Use curl/rest api to upload your file.

Save the parse file url that will be in the response from the prior POST.

use that url to download and to check the file length.

you will see that they are not changing the file size in a POST.

Then, you can either shift to the REST API in your app OR figure out where the SDK  or your app code is doing the compression that you note in your post.